# Using AES-CBC with a random number plus a counter for the IV

Tags: encryption, aes, initialisation-vector, cbc, aes-cbc

I understand that AES-CBC uses the following scheme for encrypting data (diagram [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29)):

[image: AES-CBC Diagram]

And, I understand that we don't want initialization vectors to be [predictable or constant](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/41702/64559), and also that you [don't want it to just be a plain counter](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9113/incrementing-initialization-vector-by-1).

But, what if the Initialization vector is computed with some number of random bits and then some counter. For example, 12 bytes of random data plus 4 bytes of a counter?

My understanding is that the Initialization Vector is to make the plaintext input into AES random — which, if you're using 12 bytes of random data plus 4 bytes of a counter you'll still have the first 12 of the IV providing randomness. An analog to the question might be: what would be the damage for generating random IVs, except for that the last 4 bytes are always zeros?

Obviously, you now have less entropy for your IV so are more likely to get a collision, but does the fact that the last 4 bytes are constant affect the encryption in any other way? My understanding is that the output of AES is "random-looking", so it's not like having the last 4 bytes of the IV constant would let you do a [chosen plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) on those last 4 bytes — or, am I missing something? Is there any scenario in which using a random number + counter for AES-CBC would be beneficial?

I'm mostly curious about this in the case of general communication messages, but would things change significantly if we were encrypting something predictable, like JSON with a particular format?

Bonus question: A constant IV is bad. A cryptographically random IV is good... Is there a number of constant bytes in an IV at which AES-CBC will start to show weakness, other than the higher chance of an IV collision? (How bad would a constant 8 bytes of zeroes be? How about 12 bytes?). Not looking for a specific answer for this one, but just general insight into the design of AES.

<sub>(For clarification, I'm not advocating for using the scheme I described, and it's quite certainly bad idea to use it — I'm just curious about the implications)</sub>

Comment: This is possibly a better question for crypto.stackexchange.com, as it's specifically about the properties of cryptographic constructions rather than about infosec in general. As for the actual question: off the top of my head this is probably OK in most cases for AES-CBC in particular (some other ciphers/constructions would have a problem, see e.g. weak IVs in RC4) but... _why_?! If you can support 12 bytes of random value, surely you can support 16?